# How to call ajax in a jsf page without making a full server round trip?

Tags: ajax, rest, jsf, ejb

I am writting a simple user registration process.
What I want to do is that when the user enters a username, I want to check if the username has already been taken by someone else. If it has been, then I want to show a message under the input field, asking the user to choose a different username.

I have already written the database query/ejb/rest etc...

What I want to know is ... 
**How do I make a call to the backend (ejb/rest) and show the message on the screen without having to make a full round trip to the server and refreshing the entire page?**

**Update 1:**
I have changed my code to look like the example from Simon.(Don't know why it did not appear before).

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Please enter a user name :" />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{userNameCheckBean.signInName}"
            autocomplete="off" size="20" onfocus="blankOut();" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Error: Username is required." maxlength="25">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="message" listener="#{userNameCheckBean.verifyIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken()}" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputText rendered="#{userNameCheckBean.userExists}" id="message" value="#{userNameCheckBean.message}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="checkUser" action="#{userNameCheckBean.userExists}" value="Check">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The confusing thing for me is, How do I call the verifyIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken() method when the username inputText looses focus? and how do I update just the bit of the overall form? Is it a must to have a commandButton to submit the username field? I thought ajax was meant to make server calls in the background.

**Update 2:**
I have changed the .xhtml file to the one given below. I still have to click on the button to call the backing bean. It simply ignores the event. Any help will be much appriciated.

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Please enter a user name :" />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{userNameCheckBean.signInName}" autocomplete="off" size="20" onfocus="blankOut();" required="true" requiredMessage="Error: Username is required." maxlength="25">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="blur" render="message" listener="#{userNameCheckBean.checkIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken()}" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText rendered="#{userNameCheckBean.userExists}" id="message" value="#{userNameCheckBean.message}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="checkUser" action="#{userNameCheckBean.checkIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken}" value="Check">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

**Update 3:**
Here is backing bean that works when I click on the Button.

```
package co.uk.dakia.beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import example.UserManager;
import example.ServiceLocator;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserNameCheckBean {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserNameCheckBean.class.getName());

@EJB(beanName = "UserManager", mappedName = "jndi:ext://example/UserManagerRemote")
UserManager userManager;

String signInName;

String password;

String message = "Message: ";

boolean userExists = false;

public void checkIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws NamingException, IOException {
    userManager = (UserManager) ServiceLocator.locateService("UserManagerRemote");
    logger.info("Checking if username [" + signInName + "] has already been taken by some other user");
    userExists = userManager.userExists(signInName);
    if(userExists) {
        message = "Username is already taken!";
    } else {
        message = "";
        logger.info("Username [" + signInName + "] is available.");
    }
}

public void checkIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken() throws NamingException, IOException {
    checkIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken(null);
}

public String getSignInName() {
    return signInName;
}

public void setSignInName(String signInName) {
    this.signInName = signInName;
}

public String getMessage() throws NamingException, IOException {
    checkIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken();
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public boolean isUserExists() {
    return userExists;
}

public void setUserExists(boolean userExists) {
    this.userExists = userExists;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}   
}
```

Comment: Default action of `f:ajax` on `inputText` is `change`. If you want it to execute it when it looses focus, you need to add `event="blur"`. Also, you need to wrap your `message` component into something (like a `panelGroup` always rendered, because you can't directly render a component that is not rendered.

Comment: Any stack? Any error in console? The blur event should work.

Comment: No, there is not stack trace nothing. The backing bean simply does not get called, until I click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide any code so it is hard to tell you exactly what to do, but here's a template (assuming you're using JSF 2):

.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{myBean.username}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="username-already-taken-wrapper" listener="#{myBean.verifyIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken()}"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:panelGroup id="username-already-taken-wrapper">
        <h:outputText rendered="#{myBean.usernameAlreadyTaken}" value="Username is already taken!"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    ...
</h:form>
```

MyBean.java:

```
public void verifyIfUsernameIsAlreadyTaken()
{
    usernameAlreadyTaken = verify(username);
}

private boolean verify(String username)
{
    ...
}
```

The trick is to use AJAX to submit only a part of your form (in this case: the username), and refresh only a part of the page (in this case: username-already-taken-wrapper). If the username is already taken, the message will show. If not, nothing will show.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I have updated the question again with some more changes to the .xhtml. I am still having any luck with this.